# Disable console output when executing a SQL file using MySQL source command

Tags: mysql, windows

I begin by launching the MySQL command line tool:

```
mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --silent --force -b
```

The last `-b` option is used to disable beep on error.

Then I choose a database:

```
use Mydatabasename;
```

Then I execute SQL form a file like this:

```
source c:\x\y\z\myfile.sql
```

That's when things go slowly. I've executed *part* of the file before so the console is filled with duplicate row errors which slow execution badly. I get 5-10 statements executed per second. Without duplicate rows the code executes tens of thousands of statements (30k+) every 5 seconds.

I need to do this since the file is large and I can't execute it in one go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the problem. The OS has two modes to print things

- stdout
- stderr

The `--silent`  only affects stdout. How do you nail stderr?

Try one of the following, and see if it works:

```
mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --silent --force -b 2> nul
mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --silent --force -b --tee=nul
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT : I have dealt with something this before when answering a question about mysqldump : [How to log verbose output from mysqldump?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14305/how-to-log-verbose-output-from-mysqldump/14307#14307)

Comment: Does "2>nul" mean redirect the second output stream (stderr) to nothing? I just executed my big script and I think it's still going through the duplicates (didn't use silent just 2> nul). I think I'll need to split the source file... Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, output to `NUL` writes absolutely nothing. You could do `2>stderr.txt` if you want.